Adding HEADWIND MDM with full control to grapahene OS
I am not able to integrate my Headwind MDM app with full control to graphene os. A very simple restriction i have kept in my mdm profile that i want to put in my google pixel 8a running on graphene is user should not be allowed to turn on flight mode.
I have bundled my apk in the OS but my restriction is not working. I also found out in my mdm server that the mdm mode is set to off for my profile. I guess issue is with that only. While in other stock OS this issue dont comes.
Can someone help me to grant device ownership to my mdm so that the phone can be fully controlled for work profiles

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
